# Does $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty$ represent the arbitrary union ? Does the union here reach up to $i=\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, math-history, infinity

I think the answer to this question is yes. Since up to this union it will cover all the natural as well as transfinite numbers.
But since the term $arbitrary$ has wide area what about others (like $empty\ union$ ) ?
However sometimes we have seen this symbol for countable union, while some authors use this for arbitrary union (in definition of topology).

Please clarify. What I'm missing ?

Comment: No. The convention is that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ means $\cup_{i\in  \mathbb N}A_i$.

Answer (score 8):

No, this represents a *countable* union. In this context you have a set $A_i$ for every $i \in {\mathbb N}$ and you form the union
$$\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i = \bigcup \{ A_i \mid i \in {\mathbb N}\} = \{ x \mid \exists i \in {\mathbb N}: x \in A_i\}.$$
In particular, there is no $A_\infty$ included in the union.

For an *arbitrary* union, you'd have an (arbitrary large) index set $I$ and a set $A_i$ for every $i \in I$ and you form the union
$$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup \{ A_i \mid i \in I\} = \{ x \mid \exists i \in I: x \in A_i\}.$$
Or, as suggested in the comments by Mark S., you'd have a set ${\cal A}$ whose members are sets and you form the union
$$\bigcup{\cal A} = \{x \mid \exists A \in {\cal A} : x \in A \}.$$

If you take a union up to and including some (possibly transfinite) ordinal $\beta$, you'd probably be understood if you wrote $\bigcup_{\alpha=0}^\beta A_\alpha$, but I think it is more common to write $\bigcup_{\alpha \leq \beta} A_\alpha$ in that case, especially because you can then also write $\bigcup_{\alpha < \beta} A_\alpha$ to signify that $A_\beta$ is not included in the union.

If you want to take the union over *all* ordinals, you could write $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} A_\alpha$, ignoring for a moment that this gets you in the domain of proper classes instead of sets.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by adding the unindexed union notation like $\bigcup\mathcal{A}$

Answer (score 1):

If you want the union to reach an infinite index then you need a number system that includes infinite numbers, such as the hyperreals.  Over the hyperreals you can indeed have infinite indices $H$ and hyperfinite unions of the type $\bigcup_{i=1}^{H}$.

In other words, what you are missing is that infinite unions "up to a cardinal" don't make sense (at least not without further effort).

Comment: Is it "teach an infinite index", or maybe "take"?

Comment: @amrsa, thanks, I corrected the misprint.

Comment: I understand Robinson's hyperreals, but it's not obvious to me what your hyperfinite union is supposed to mean. Do you have sets $A_i$ for every positive hyperinteger up to $i=H$? That would be a weird setting since those hyperintegers aren't well-ordered, but I suppose you could take the union then.

Comment: @MarkS., of course whenever you have a union indexed by *any* set (in particular the set of hypernaturals from $1$ to $H$), you can form a the corresponding union.  However the point of *internal* hyperfinite unions (and hyperfinite sums and products) is that they behave like finite ones. For example, in the proof of the extreme value theorem via a hyperfinite partition, one can choose the point of the partition where the value of the function is maximal, even though there are infinitely many points.  Of course the *internal* property is the key (and the set of values of a standard function...

Comment: ...at the points of a hyperfinite partition *is* internal. I would say that the understanding of internal entities is what distinguishes a student of infinitesimal calculus from a student of infinitesimal analysis.

Comment: By the way, the hypernaturals are indeed *internally* well-ordered.  This means that any *internal* subset has a least element.